# Использование ресурсов приложения Windows, LoadString()

Tags: windows, c++

Если в оконном приложении у меня имеется строка статуса, в которой могут отображаться N-различных сообщений, имеет ли смысл весь набор этих сообщений оформить через ресурс приложения String Table и в дальнейшем загружать требуемое сообщение используя:

```
int WINAPI LoadString(
 _In_opt_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
 _In_      UINT uID,
 _Out_     LPTSTR lpBuffer,
 _In_      int nBufferMax);
```

Как я понимаю, данные будут браться непосредственно из исполняемого файла по мере запросов. Тогда возникает вопрос, если в момент запроса, HDD будет находится в спящем режиме, то потребуется время на его пробуждение и только после этого я получу свою строку. И вообще как много ресурсов системы тратится на эту процедуру?
Как оформить код, что бы он работал эффективно?

Comment: - Данные ресурсов грузятся при запуске программы, а не лениво, поэтому обращения к диску в этом случае не будет.

- Почему вообще возник этот вопрос? Вы написали какой-то код и он у вас работает медленно? Или вы занимаетесь `premature optimization`?

Comment: Ещё не написал! Только пишу! Сразу хотелось бы закладывать правильный код! Как мне кажется использование ресурсов это есть оптимальный подход!?

Comment: @rejie

- Восклицательный знак после каждого предложения - это сильно!

- Для вашей задачи (если не использовать сторонние методы для интернационализации) подход с `LoadString` выглядит неплохим.

Comment: >Для вашей задачи (если не использовать сторонние методы для интернационализации) подход с LoadString выглядит неплохим

Более того, если использовать `FindResource` и `LoadResource` и вычислять адреса строк вручную, не потребуется даже строкового буфера, который передается в LoadString, хотя это будут исключительно UNICODE-строки.

Вобщем-то, это ответ на вопрос:
>как много ресурсов системы тратится на эту процедуру

т.е. нисколько, если не считать сам исполняемый образ PE и поиск ресурса в секции ресурсов.

Хотя, на этом этапе, вопрос не принципиальный.